# Any idea why XLSM File automatically closes on open only on one computer on network?

Tags: excel, vba

We have over 10 computers on our network and everyone's computer opens up the file with no issue. Even this one computer that is having it automatically close on open used to have it work without a problem until this morning. I created a copy of the file to see if it was the file that was corrupted but when the copy is opened the same thing happens. Does anyone have any idea why this would start happening, I do not see any problems with the code. The computers are operating on windows 10 pro. Here is the code that runs on open, it is only supposed to close workbook x but it is closing y as well only on his computer starting today.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim z As Integer
Set x = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="*FilePath*", ReadOnly:=True)
Set y = Workbooks("MonthlyLog")
x.Sheets("Distribution Lists").Range("A2:F1200").Copy
y.Sheets("Distribution Lists").Range("A124:F1322").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Close
If month(Now) = 1 Then
    z = 12
Else
    z = month(Now) - 1
End If
Sheets(MonthName(z)).Activate

Application.Calculation = xlManual

End Sub
```

It isn't asking to repair anything just prompting to save right upon opening and if Save or Do Not Save are chosen then it closes, only when cancel is clicked it stays open.

Comment: make sure that the computer does not have a `PERSONAL.XLSB` workbook - it gets loaded when Excel starts.
try to check in `C:\Users\<username>\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB`

Comment: if you add `Debug.Assert False` line in your `Workbook_Open` (or better make a new workbook with just that as it's `Workbook_Open`) it will break any running macros. This can help you spot what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I will try those out, so I am assuming I should delete Personal.XLSB on that computer?

Comment: What is `"*FilePath*"`?

Comment: Set a breakpoint a `Set x` and at `End Sub` and run the whole thing from the debugger. See where/when `y` is closed. Do not use the Step command; that can produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by opening the file in safe mode and saving it.